# From Excel get the dimensions of a shape in PowerPoint with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm trying to build a tool whereby users can click a button in Excel and get the height, width, top, left properties of a selected shape in PowerPoint (to enable them to size shapes in Excel more effectively).

Currently I don't seem to be able to reference the selected shape in PowerPoint despite having the following code:

```
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim ActivePresentation As Object
Dim ActiveSlide As Object

Public Sub getDimensionsFromPowerPoint()

    'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
    On Error Resume Next

    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
    Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
    err.Clear

    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
    If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
    If err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Create a New Presentation

    Set ActiveShape = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.ActiveWindow.Selection

    Debug.Print ActiveShape.width

End Sub
```

I have a feeling I'm not interacting with PowerPoint properly but cannot see how else it can be.

Comment: Try `debug.Print typename(ActiveShape)` to verify your assumption that you have got a shape.  Where is ActiveShape defined in your code?

Comment: i don't know how to do it in powerpoint, but in excel it is like that : `Dim Pic as Shape : Set Pic = Selection.Shaperange(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 Set ActiveShape = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.ActiveWindow.Selection
```

Use:

```
 Set ActiveShape = PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

From this web page  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745871.aspx

It looks like you need to use the ShapeRange method to get references to shapes.

I think ShapeRange supports For Each because (1) so you can loop through them.

(1) Evidence for support For Each is presence of hidden _NewEnum method.